# React Native Web Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: styles is not defined

Tags: react-native, styles, expo, react-native-web

I'm trying to make a prototype of application with React Native, compatible for WEB browser, and iOS. iOS simulator is rendering without any problem, but the web browser, instead, is giving me error. It happens when using the external file defining the style.

Should there be any difference for linking the external style file with webbrowser and iOS?

When including the style code inside the js file, it works without any problem, but error occurs when trying to make the style codes external file.

Error:

> ReferenceError: styles is not defined

Style code(external file)

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ddd',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Main js file trying to import style

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, } from 'react-native';
import styles from '../styles.js'

export default class Profile extends React.Component{

  render(){
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Profile</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the import directory is correct? `import styles from '../styles.js'` if so, try to remove the .js, try this `import styles from '../styles'`

Comment: Hi NARIO, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, ravibagul91's solution works perfetcly. And Michael, the path was right, since I put the main.js under the screen folder, but thanks anyway! You guys made my day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the assignemnt to a variable, try this,

```
export default StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ddd',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

or may be this,

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ddd',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default styles
```

Or you can do this,

```
export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ddd',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

And then import is as,

```
import { styles } from '../styles'  //Make sure the path is correct
```

**Note:** I doubt about the file path. Basically `main.js` file is in `src` folder and importing a file with path `../` means you are stepping out 1 folder up. If `styles.js` file is in same folder where you have `main.js` file, you just need to import like this,

```
import { styles } from './styles'  //Here `./` means the same folder.
```

Comment: Thanks ravibagul91, the 1st code you wrote works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the StyleSheet is imported from react-native module

```
import {StyleSheet} from "react-native";
```